# Regex expression cuts zero in the end

Tags: powershell, regex

I have a script with powershell regex in it, and after I upgraded from Windows 7 to 10 it working different.

Regex:

```
if ($srv -match '^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$'){$srv = "192.168.$srv"}
```

Expected:

```
Let's say that $srv="1.0"
result: 192.168.1.0
```

After I upgraded it to Windows 10, it just cuts the zero in the end.

```
Now result will be: 192.168.1
BUT! if $srv="1.01", the result will be 192.168.1.01
```

I searched for regex difference between powershell versions, but found nothing.
Please help :)

Comment: Can you show the output of following command `$srv = "1.0";if ($srv -match '^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$'){"192.168.$srv"}`

Comment: The output is "192.168.1.0"(as expected) In my script $srv is $args[0], but I don't change it or something before.

Comment: Thus it's not the regex and it's not the variable so it's nothing you are currently showing us. Unless you show a minimum script that has the same problems, I doubt we can be of much help. Note that by creating such a minimal script, you are likely to find the problem and solution all at once :)

Comment: igor, I suggest running the script in the ISE debugger. Single step through it and see what `$srv` gets set to.

Answer (score 0):

You say the output of

> $srv = "1.0"; if ($srv -match '^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$') {"192.168.$srv"}

is `192.168.1.0`

And if I understand correctly, when you use

> $srv = $args[0]; if ($srv -match '^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$') {"192.168.$srv"}

And pass `1.0` as an argument, the output is `192.168.1`

The only way this is possible is if your script is outputting this *somewhere else*. Since it can not be coming from this `if` statement.

Could you make the following changes to your script, and show us the output:

> $srv = $args[0];
>   "srv = $srv";
>   if ($srv -match '^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$') {"Inside IF: 192.168.$srv"}

Thanks